# Stage controller tutorial on Groovy

Tags: microcontroller, simulation, laser, tutorial, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to follow the stage controller tutorial here: [ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/IntroductiontoStageControllers](http://ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/IntroductiontoStageControllers).

However, I run into the following errors:

```
err: Model type laser not found in model typetable (/tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-stage-1.6.7/debian/ros-groovy-stage/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/world.cc CreateModel)

err: Unknown model type laser in world file. (/tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-stage-1.6.7/debian/ros-groovy-stage/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/world.cc CreateModel)
```

I replaced laser with ranger in roomba-wander.world and got the following warnings:

```
warn: lookup of model name roomba.ranger:1: no matching name (/tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-stage-1.6.7/debian/ros-groovy-stage/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/world.cc GetModel)

warn: Model roomba.ranger:1 not found (/tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-stage-1.6.7/debian/ros-groovy-stage/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/stage/build/stage/libstage/model.cc GetChild)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Now I read this topic, [answers.ros.org/question/33973/stage-error-in-fuerte/](http://answers.ros.org/question/33973/stage-error-in-fuerte/), but the solutions are for fuerte. I tried them anyway, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to fix this? Or is there another similar tutorial that I could follow? I need to simulate a navigating robot (I will use an icreate), and eventually implement SLAM.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62540/stage-controller-tutorial-on-groovy/) by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 343 on 2013-05-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There has been known issues with Stage Controllers ever since fuerte and they have not been conclusively resolved. You may have seen this little note on top of the Stage Controller Tutorials, which confirms to what I am saying here;

> **Note**: This tutorial works on ROS
> Electric but has known issues in ROS
> Fuerte and ROS Groovy

If you want to navigate an icreate and attempt SLAM then there are other simpler ways to achieve that. I will suggest that you use a simple navigation/wander like code and team it up with gmapping and map_server.

Here are 2 samples, they are in stage and gazebo respectively but they should give you a good idea about what I am talking about.

1. http://mobotica.blogspot.in/2011/11/maps-from-stage-simulations-in-ros-part.html ( uses teleoperation in stage, in ROS diamondback but it should work in most of the other distributions)
2. http://answers.ros.org/question/12636/slam-in-gazebo/ (in gazebo)

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2013-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-05-12**:
Thanks so much, I will look that up!